# Dockerfile pip install not working on openshift for xgboost

Tags: python, docker, openshift, dockerfile, xgboost

So my team at work had put together a simple python service and had a dockerfile that performs some small tasks like pip installing dependencies, creating a user, rewiring some directories etc.

Everything worked fine locally -- we were able to build and run a docker image locally on my laptop (I have a MacBook Pro, running High Sierra if that is relevant).

We attempted to build the project on Openshift and kept getting a "Generic Build error" which told us to check the logs.

The log line it was failing on was 
`RUN pip3 install pandas flask-restful xgboost scikit-learn nltk scipy`
and there was no related error listed with it. It literally just stopped at that point.

Specifically, it was breaking out when it got to installing xgboost. We removed the xgboost part and the entire Dockerfile ran fine and the build completed successfully so we know it was definitely just that one install causing the issue. Has anyone else encountered this and know why it happens?
We are pretty certain it wasn't any kind of memory or storage issue as the container had plenty of room for how small the service was.

**Note**: We were able to eventually use a coworker's template image to get our project up with the needed dependencies, just curious why this was happening in case we run into a similar issue in the future

Comment: When you say building in OpenShift, what OpenShift setup is that? Are you using Minishift, an OpenShift environment you built from scratch yourself, or some hosted OpenShift environment? When it always fails on a certain package, especially some of the numpy and scipy packages, it can be that you have run out of memory if build quotas exist. If you use ``oc get events`` it should show when a build is failed because of that.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton it is an OpenShift Origin prod environment that was configured by a different team and handed over to us. Will try that command if we run into the issue again though. I'm pretty sure the build quota was 3 or 4 gib so I don't think that was the problem. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an option for you, but when I need to build from a Dockerfile, I usually use a hosted service like [Quay.io](http://quay.io) or DockerHub.